# whats wrong in this perl script?

Tags: perl

I want to delete those .txt files in a folder that has <=3 of ">" character starting as header. As a beginner in perl scripting, I have used:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $file = glob '*.txt' ) {

open my $fh, '<', $file;
my $headers = grep /^>/, <$fh>;

    if ($headers <= 3) {
        unlink '$file';
    }
}
```

After executing it won't delete any files and won't show any errors either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are unlinking the literal string `'$file'`. Drop the single quotes `''`. They don't do interpolation.

Comment: I don't agree with the close-vote for _no mcve_. This question is very well written. It's a facepalm-type mistake and a close-vote for _typo_ would be ok in my opinion, but besides that it's a really good question. I wish we would get more questions of this quality.

Comment: You already got several answers when you posted [here](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1176082)

Comment: I do agree that it's bad practice to cross-post the same question without telling us. What is funny though is that it seems you asked on perlmonks _first_, but you don't have the single quotes there.